# Problem printing array from indented structures in C

Tags: c, struct, printf

So I'm new to the struct subject and I'm trying to make a program that contains and indented structure and trying to print some data to the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Asignature
{
    char *subject[1];
};

struct Student
{
    int accNum;
    char name[20];
    char lastName[20];
    float average;
    struct Asignature subjects[5];
};


int main(void)
{
    struct Student student1 = {1, "Adolfo", "Roman", 8.8, {{"EDA"}, {"Calculus"}, {"Lineal"}}};
    struct Student student2 = {2, "Patricia", "Mora", 9.8, {{"Psicology"}, {"Medicine"},{ "Psicoanalitics"}}};

    struct Student *ptr_student1;
    struct Student *ptr_student2;

    ptr_student1 = &student1;
    ptr_student1 = &student2;


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", ptr_student1->subjects[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

So that's the code I wrote, but compiler gives me this error:

```
~/eda/practica3/ $ make previo
clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wshadow    previo.c  -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o previo
previo.c:35:20: error: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'struct Asignature' [-Werror,-Wformat]
    printf("%s\n", ptr_student1->subjects[i]);
```

When I compile in the website onlinegdb it seems to work fine.

I'm not really sure how to modify %s to a "struct" type...

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you that the format specifier `%s` means that you want to print a null-terminated character string, but you pass in `ptr_student1->subjects[i]` which is a `struct Asignature`. You need to go a level deeper: `ptr_student1->subjects[i].subject[0]`.

Side note:

```
char *subject[1];
```

This is strange because you are declaring an array with one element. If there is only one item, then you don't need an array at all:

```
char *subject;
```

Similarly, `struct Asignature` only contains `subject`, so why do we need a struct? You can change `struct Student` to hold an array of strings:

```
struct Student
{
int accNum;
char name[20];
char lastName[20];
float average;
char* subjects[5];
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I will check it right now. Regarding why the struct Asignature contains only one element, the answer it's our teacher told us to do the excercise that way so we can understand how to print the elements indexed inside other structs I guess.

Thanks for your help! I understand how to do it way better now :)